# Create Spring.Data.Cassandra keyspace in runtime

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

I am using Cassandra in my Spring Boot app. When I start the app, the keyspace is automatically created and everything is okay. The problem is that I want to create keyspace in runtime. For example from endpoint or from application.properties. I have tried only with @RefreshScope and after that with

> spring.cloud.refresh.extra-refreshable=spring.data.cassandra.keyspace-name

and sent POST on actuator/refresh but both solutions does not work. The Class is simple Person class with @Table annotation.

So my question is: Is it possible to create keyspace in runtime after sending request to actuator/refresh???

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And this is what I have in application.properties

```
#spring.data.cassandra.keyspace-name=test1_keyspace
#spring.data.cassandra.schema-action=CREATE_IF_NOT_EXISTS
#spring.data.cassandra.contact-points=IP
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that with this:

```
@Component
class MySessionRefresh {

  @Autowired
  Environment env;

  @Autowired
  Session session;

  // omitted constructors for brevity

  @EventListener
  @Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)
  public void handle(RefreshScopeRefreshedEvent event) {

    String keyspace = env.getProperty("spring.data.cassandra.keyspace-name");
    session.execute("CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS " + keyspace + " WITH REPLICATION = { 'class' : 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'datacenter1' : 3 };");
  }
}
```